# Extending meromorphic function of $C^n-\{0\}$ to $C^n$

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

This is related to Kodaira's Complex Manifolds and Deformation of Complex Structure Chpt 2, Sec 2's Hopf Manifold example.

Consider $W=C^n-\{0\}$, $a=(a_1,\dots, a_n)\in C^n-\{0\}$ with $|a_i|>1$. $a$ acts on $W$ by multiplying individual components. Then $G=<a>$ is the multiplicative group generated by $a$. Clearly $W/G$ is a complex manifold. Pick $f$ meromorphic function on $W/G$ and lift it to $W$.

$\textbf{Q:}$ The book says the function $f$ defined on $C^n-\{0\}$ extends to $C^n$ by Levi Extension Theorem.(I guess this $f$ does not have to be $G$ equivariant for extension purpose.) Consider $n=1$ and $exp(1/z)$ which can never be extended to $C$ as it has infinite order pole at $z=0$ but local germ at $0$ is always quotient of 2 polynomials up to invertible elements. So $n\geq 2$ or does $f$ require $G$ equivariance?

Comment: @reuns I am considering 2 cases. Assume there is a meromorphic function on $W/G$ and lift it to $W$ by setting it as $f$.(In general, there will be none.) For application Levi extension theorem, I do not see requirement $f$ being $G-$equivariant as assumption or I remembered the wrong statement. Then apply "Levi extension theorem" to get extended. If "Levi extension theorem" does not depend on $G-$equivariance, then it could be applied directly to any meromorphic function $f$. I think somehow I need $G-$equivariance but I did not find correct Levi extension thm.

Comment: @reuns In that case, it is not hopf manifold as it is not given by quotient of contraction mapping near 0. The whole point of the section is to demonstrate when there is meromorphic section on hopf manifold and when such lifted section over $C^n-0$ can be extended to $C^n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it should be assumed that $n\geq 2$.  The Levi extension theorem only applies in dimensions $n\geq 2$.  When $n=1$, there are always lots of meromorphic functions on a Hopf manifold (indeed, it is an elliptic curve).